# Java Spring: @Scheduled annotation reports an error when selecting MICROSECONDS as a time unit

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

According to the Spring documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html we can use various time units to tune our period tasks (default is millisecond).

I want to have a task with granularity 1 MICROSECOND. Therefore I have defined:

```
    @Scheduled(timeUnit = TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS, fixedDelay = 1, initialDelay = 1000)
    public void scheduleTask() throws IdaDatabaseException {...}
```

But when starting an application or an integration test I experience an error (s. below).
What is wrong with the micosecond-granularity?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [MergedContextConfiguration@27d45d8 testClass = com.ida.sr.IdaIsrDbReceiverTest, locations = [], classes = [com.ida.sr.IdaIsrDbReceiver, com.ida.database.config.IdaDatabaseServiceConfiguration, com.ida.tz.appconfig.TzKafkaConfiguration, com.ida.tz.appconfig.TzKafkaConsumerConfiguration, com.ida.appconfig.IdaMonitoringConfig, com.ida.sr.KafkaTestConfig], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = ["classpath:application-test.properties"], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer@cc7406bd, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@9da1, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@7c9bdee9, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@221dad51, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@73a19967, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@756b58a7, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@4514ad9b], contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:142)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:141)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:97)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:241)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy5.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:671)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ConcurrentTaskScheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(ConcurrentTaskScheduler.java:247)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.config.ScheduledTaskRegistrar.scheduleFixedDelayTask(ScheduledTaskRegistrar.java:525)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.config.ScheduledTaskRegistrar.scheduleTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar.java:406)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.config.ScheduledTaskRegistrar.afterPropertiesSet(ScheduledTaskRegistrar.java:371)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.finishRegistration(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:319)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:238)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:413)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:370)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:587)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:59)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:47)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1386)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:118)
    ... 44 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that you've found a bug in how the scheduler works.  It purports to accept a `TimeUnit`, but if you look at the `ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`, you'll see these lines:

```
long fixedDelay = convertToMillis(scheduled.fixedDelay(), scheduled.timeUnit());
if (fixedDelay >= 0) {
    Assert.isTrue(!processedSchedule, errorMessage);
    ...
}
```

The first part of this converts your microseconds to milliseconds.  That logic simply does a division, `duration / milliRatio`.  Your duration is set to `1` per the fixedDelay property, the ratio of milliseconds to microseconds is 1000, so this returns 1/1000, which rounds up to 0.  This will drop you into the `if` block and since this process has yet to be scheduled, fails the assertion and throws the caught exception.

In other words, it looks like if you pass in microseconds or nanoseconds as a time unit, it's not going to work.

You might think that you can set this to something that will equate to a positive value, but then you'll find another trap a few lines lower when it checks the fixed rate.

Comment: Believe it or not, but I have debugged yesterday this part of the code and overseen this conversion :)) Thanx a lot for pointing out!